# Java Binary file upload to APIGateway with S3 backend

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have an Amazon ApiGateway that handle the upload and download from S3 buckets as explained here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html

The client is written in plain java using some AWS example code.
My issue is with PUT method: Text file are correctly uploaded but binary file like images appears as string of bytes.

This is the code I use to upload:

```
byte [] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileToUpload));

/* For string I use this line:          
String objectContent=new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
*/
//For Image file I need to convert with this
String objectContent=Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);

Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("x-amz-content-sha256", contentHashString);
headers.put("x-amz-storage-class", "REDUCED_REDUNDANCY");
            
AWS4SignerForAuthorizationHeader signer = new AWS4SignerForAuthorizationHeader(endpointUrl, "PUT", "execute-api", regionName);
String authorization = signer.computeSignature(headers,null, // no query parameters
                                                           contentHashString, 
                                                           aws_access_key_id, 
                                                           aws_secret_access_key);
                    
// express authorization for this as a header
headers.put("Authorization", authorization);
            
// make the call to Amazon API Gateway
String response = HttpUtils2.invokeHttpRequest(endpointUrl, "PUT", headers, objectContent);
```

Possibily the error is on the way I convert the content to string to post.

Comment: Yes. you are converting the image to text. It will be stored as text only. Check the example once again. The example must be for uploading the image but as a base64 string .

Comment: Unfortunately the example upload a short text and there's nothing on binary.